# create table message and request

Tags: mysql, message

I want to create a messaging and requests system.

The messages:
be able to send between the users

The requests:
send friend requests to an user and make sure that the user recieves the request

How can i put the tables and relationships of MYSQL?

regards

Comment: http://whatHaveYouTried.com ?

Comment: why not use any of the existing open source messaging system already out there?  Like Jabber, or even irc.  Chat is a really poor use-case for relational databases.

Comment: i would like to know how to desingn in mysql myself. can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

```
create table users(
  id integer,
  name  string,
  email # if needed (to send to).
  )

create table messages(
  id integer,
  message text,
  from_user_id integer,
  to_user_id  integer,
  sent_on datetime,
  received_on datetime,
  read_on datetime)
```

It's up to you to populate the `sent_on` / `received_on` / `read_on` appropriately in your application.